# expected initializer before ‘<’ token

Tags: c++, templates

The following is my test code. I just want to know what type of the point is.But I got an error while compiling at line "bool instanceOf(A* msg)". How to correct it. thx.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A   
class B : public A
class C : public A   
template <class T>
bool instanceOf<T>(A* msg)
{
    T *tmp = dynamic_cast<T *>(msg);
    if(NULL == tmp)
        return false;
    return true;
}
void resolveMsgType(A* msg)
{       
    if(instanceOf<B>(msg))
    {
        cout<<"this is class B"<<endl;
    }else if(instanceOf<C>(msg)){
        cout<<"this is class C"<<endl;
    }else{
        cout<<"error"<<endl;
    }       
}

int main()
{
    A *a;
    a = new B();
    resolveMsgType(a);
    a = new C();
    resolveMsgType(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I hope that e.g. `class A` is just a placeholder and not real code?

Comment: on a side note, why use:

`if(NULL == tmp)
    return false;
return true;`

when you can write

`return tmp!=NULL;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class A   
class B : public A
class C : public A
```

isn't valid C++, did you mean

```
class A  {};
class B : public A {};
class C : public A {};
```

?

Also note that `dynamic_cast` only works with polymorphic classes.

Also, unless you're specializing the template method for a type, the correct syntax is:

```
template <class T>
bool instanceOf(A* msg)
//             ^
//       note no <T>
```

Comment: thx,the definition is just fake code. and the destrcution methods are virtual to make they are polymorphic classes.

Answer (score 4):

It's enough do define the method like this:

```
template <class T>
bool instanceOf(A* msg) { ... }
```

So just strip out the `<T>` after **instanceOf** - the compiler already knows it's a templated function.

Answer (score 0):

For your purpose, wouldn't this be simpler

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class A
{
public:
    virtual void resolveMsgType(){};
};  
class B : public A
{
public:
    void resolveMsgType()
    {
        cout<<"this is class b";
    }
};
class C : public A
{
public:
    void resolveMsgType()
    {
        cout<<"this is class c";
    }
} ;  
int main()
{
    A *a = new B();
    a->resolveMsgType();
    a = new C();
    a->resolveMsgType();
    cin.ignore();
}
```

Also to use `dynamic_cast`, the parameter should be of polymorphic type. So in your case, the code will not compile.

Answer (score 0):

Your instanceOf function should be like this:

```
template <class T>
bool instanceOf(A* msg)
{
    T *tmp = dynamic_cast<T *>(msg);
    return tmp != NULL;
}
```

you dont need  after function name.